# Finding a source for על טעם וריח

Tags: sources-mekorot

There is a quote: על טעם וריח אין להתוכח. I've heard this attributed to חז"ל, but it seems more like a folk saying. What is the source of this?

Comment: על ריח וטעם יש מחלוקת כל פעם

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Burt and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @DoubleAA where did you get that from

Comment: @Burt first overheard it in a judaica store in meah sharim maybe 15+ years ago

Comment: I asked this very question to my rebbe a few years ago, and his answer was "Mistoma some girls' school."

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%98%D7%A2%D7%9D_%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%97_%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%97) it was coined by an Israeli writer named [Avraham Shlonsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avraham_Shlonsky).